# Is WhatsApp providing any API's for status uploading to it's Business platform

Tags: whatsapp

As I mentioned above, are there any API's available for uploading status (text, images and videos etc.) in the WhatsApp Businesses platform?
For businesses messaging we can use  Cloud API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api
or On-Premises API
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises .
Like messages API's, I am searching for status uploading API's. If anyone knows about this please guide me.

Comment: No, there is no any API in WhatsApp Business API to upload status on WhatsApp.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a third-party solution gateway for this.
Statuses can be pictures or just text with a colored background.

A mandatory parameter should be an array of numbers to which the status will be displayed (including your own)

```js
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    accept: 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    authorization: 'Bearer Your_Token'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    background_color: '#00000000',
    caption_color: '#FFFFFFFF',
    caption: 'Hello world',
    font_type: 'SANS_SERIF',
    // media: 'data:image/png;name=test.png;base64,iVBORw0KG...........',
    contacts: ['any number', 'any number']
  })
};

fetch('https://gate.whapi.cloud/stories', options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Read more about the method here: https://whapi.readme.io/reference/createstory

You will need a token from [provider](https://whapi.cloud). Attention, this is an unofficial solution, so use at your own risk.